# For loop - add something after first item and then every 2 items after

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am creating a for loop to append some data to an element. What I would like to do is append an additional element after the first item in the array, and then add the same additional element after every 2 items afterwards:

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'Pink', 'Black'];
  
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    $('.container').append('<div>' + arr[i] + '</div>');
    
    // Place after first array value
    if (i === 0) {
      $('.container').append('<hr/>');
    }
    
    // Place after every two array values after first
    if(i != 0 && i % 2 === 0) {
      $('.container').append('<hr/>');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

This is working as desired, but I want to make sure there isn't a simpler/cleaner/more efficient way of doing this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the check to the head of the `for` loop and check for odd numbers.

```js
$(function() {
    var arr = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'Pink', 'Black'];
  
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (i % 2) {
            $('.container').append('<hr/>');
        }
        $('.container').append('<div>' + arr[i] + '</div>');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Much cleaner, thanks!